# Initialising a database before Spring Boot test

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using JUnit to test my application and everything works fine as long as the database has been initialised before the testing (using `gradle bootRun` to run as a web-app). However, if the database is empty, the application does not seem to initialise any models or entities before testing. Is there a way I'm supposed to do this? I made an assumption that the `ApplicationRunner` class will be ran before the test and initalise the entities. Is there a way to do this or am I using the wrong approach?

This is how my `application.properties` file is looking like:

```
server.port=8090
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-password 123456
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy:org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
application.logger.org.springframework=INFO
```

My database is stored in `/src/main/java/application/persistence/DbConfig.java` using a `DriverManagerDataSource` connection. And I have setup `ApplicationRunner` to run add a few rows to the db upon starting.

edit:

I should also add that these are the annotations I'm using on the JUnit test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={
    AdeyTrackApplication.class, 
    SecurityConfig.class, 
    WebConfig.class,
    AuthorizationController.class
    })
```

Comment: First way is initialize database in `setUp` method in your test class. Another way is to create test configuration where you add `@PostConstruct` function which initialize data in database and add this class to `ContextConfiguration`.

Comment: @krynio is there an example of an implementation of this? I'm not very experienced with Spring, and I haven't come across this annotation in regards to JUnit.

Comment: The simplest way is inject JdbcTemplate into your test class. Next you can execute sql query using `jdbcTemplate.execue(sql)`. To run this code before each test you should create `setUp` method with annotation `@Before`. Here is example how to inject JdbcTemplate and execute query: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-flyway/src/test/java/sample/flyway/SampleFlywayApplicationTests.java and here is example of using `@Before` http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The above answers all use the .sql schema loading technique where I'd have to have a .sql schema for tests. I didn't want to do it that way as my schema would be expanding and I'd rather not go through the hassle of adding entries to the schema as my tests expand.

As I'm using Spring Boot, I came across this annotation which seems to solve the issue by first running `bootRun` and then running the tests.

In my test annotations I replaced the `@ContextConfigurations` with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and left all the classes to be the same. This seemed to solve the issue. So now the `test` task invokes bootRun to load the classes and **then** runs the tests.

See [@SpringApplicationConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications)

Hop this helps anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: SpringApplicationConfiguration is now deprecated. 
`as of 1.4 in favor of SpringBootTest or direct use of SpringBootContextLoader`

Answer (score 47):

There are various options if you do not want to execute that explicitly from `@Before` JUnit hook.

1. Use [Spring Boot's JDBC initialization feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts), where you would place `schema.sql` or `data.sql` into `src/test/resources` folder, so that it would be picked up only during testing.
2. Use [Spring's @Sql annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql)

Comment: but @sql cannot support only execute once per class

Answer (score 12):

You can use @Sql annotaion for populate your DB, for example^

```
@Sql(scripts = "classpath:db/populateDB.sql")
```

Comment: the db folder should be inside in resources folder. Ex: test/resources/db, else it doesnt work.