# How to set up initial data for different databases?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

please help me I'm new to this business. I'm writing a Spring Boot Web Application for CV and I'd like to create a separate DB for test purposes. What is the best way to do it?
Currently, I initialize my main MySQL DB using Hibernate feature import.sql and it's working fine for the main DB. What's the best way to create a test DB? I tried with h2 base but my import.sql overrides h2 base data. Is it possible to set up data for the second (another) DB using import.sql?

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38265806/4671372 ?

Comment: No, but it helped me to find a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialising a database before Spring Boot test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38262430/initialising-a-database-before-spring-boot-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. It's the same as with the main DB. I had to create a new resource folder in the test package and pasted here import.sql (for test DB). That's all!